# Problems trying to compile in C with OpenCV

Tags: c, opencv, compiler-errors, arm

I'm  trying to compile a C code with OpenCV in  ARM. When I try to compile, I'm using the next flags

```
-L/usr/lib
-lpthread
-lrt
-l
-I/usr/local/include/opencv
-I/usr/local/include
-L/usr/local/lib
-lopencv_core
-lopencv_imgproc
-lopencv_highgui
-lopencv_ml
-lopencv_video
-lopencv_features2d
-lopencv_calib3d
-lopencv_objdetect
-lopencv_contrib
-lopencv_legacy
-lopencv_flann
```

and I get this error:

```
cannot find -lopencv_core
cannot find -lopencv_imgproc
cannot find -lopencv_flann
```

My `pkg-config` `--cflags` opencv:

```
-I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include
```

and `pkg-config` `--libs` opencv:

```
-L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_flann
```

What's wrong here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you've checked that opencv_core/flann .a files are in /usr/lib or /usr/local/lib?

Comment: I have the  opencv_core / flann .so files in /usr/local/lib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your compile lines imply that you are linking to static libraries so you need .a files not .so (.shared object). See:

[Linking to static/dynamic libraries.](http://yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html)

for maybe helpful info. Although linux oriented, it is not linux specific. I am assuming you are using gcc and not llvm, though the compiler flags may be the same.

Comment: I've done a simple program in C with OpenCV, and it works perfect with the same configuration. It's strange. I've not added the .a files

Comment: If you run ldd against the binary spat out by the compile that works I assume it shows the opencv .so files linked into binary?